# increase the count is always 0 and incrementing +1. After i do it many time the count increase 1 and show 0

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, count

I am working on the status part. which means that from db i will get success or failure message. In my code i need to increase the count if i get success at every time. Like same initially my count will be `0`. if i get success response then my count will be `1` know . this is fine. But i am doing api call man times. when i do it again my count again starting from 0 and increasing by 1. Not increasing after 1 or initially it still keeping as 0.

here my code:

```
var count = 0

function {

print(self.count)
print("initial counts: \(self.count)")
if( success ) {

self.count += 1
 print(self.count)
print("after increase / success counts: \(self.count)")

}

else {

// show error pop up failure
}


}
```

What i am doing wrong. should i need to save the increased count every time once i do the call.I yes, how can i save and use that to increase the count always.

i am using swift 3.0 Thanks in advance !!

Comment: Where have you declared `var count = 0`?

Comment: globally at top of `viewdidload `

Comment: Whenever you close the application or change view the count will restart, are you aware of that?

Comment: i am from hybrid platform. Sorry. so now how can i save locally my count and use it again with my code.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you change `view` or close the application and reopen it your variable `count` will restart at at 0 as you have declared it.

Since you´re only storing a number you can use `UserDefaults` for this purpose:

```
// Get value
count = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "count")

// Set
UserDefaults.standard.set(count, forKey: "count")
```

So what you do is that you set your `count` variable to your `UserDefaults.standard.integer` value at start and then append as you do to your `count` variable , whenever you´re done you just use the `UserDefaults.standard.set` and store the new `count`.

Comment: okay will check it out. but i have one doubt . in my code i have declared the `let count = 0 ` to use in this view controller. But if i want to use this same count in some other view controller means where should i need to declare and use it

Comment: Yes you do, you need to have a new counter, but do always use the `UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "count")` to get the current count if you want to use the same.

Comment: @hybridDev, if my answer was useful, click the upvote button to the left of it. If it answered your question, click the checkmark to accept it. That way others know that you've been (sufficiently) helped.